docker volume mapping file read only
I have a docker-compose file that maps a volume to the host.
When the mapping is a folder mapping I can write to the files in that folder from the container.
When I change the mapping to a specific file that file is read-only from the container and I have no idea why. I assume it can not be host file system permissions otherwise the file would also be read-only via the folder volume mapping.
docker-compose:
  domain-service:
    container_name: domain-service
    build:
      context: ../..
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ../../sqlite.db:/sqlite.db #file read only
      # ../../:/db. #db folder and contents writable from the container
    environment:
      APP_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
    depends_on:
      - multi-stub



A normal Unix mount is always a directory, and so Docker needs to take some extended actions to make it possible to mount a specific file.  This can also vary in VM-based setups like Docker Desktop, where the VM environment also needs to map files between the actual host and the Linux VM running the Docker daemon.  If mounting the directory works, can you do that instead?  Or can you use a separate database container (maybe backed by a Docker named volume) instead of SQLite?
